# Passing a Structure with a Memory field in JNA

Tags: java, c, malloc, jna

My dynamic C library receives some (pointer to) structures that include an allocated pointer (by malloc). The called function is allowed to call `realloc` on it.

```
typedef struct mystruct {
    void * buf;
    int buflen;
    /* more fields... */
} mystruct;


void myfunc(mystruct  *s1, /* more args*/) {  /* in dynamic library */
   /* .... */
      s1->buf = realloc(s1->buf,newsize);
   /* .... */
}
```

I thought that a Structure with a [Memory](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Memory.html) field would do the trick,

```
public class MyStructJna extends Structure {
    public Memory buf;
    public Integer buflen;
            /* .... */
}
```

but then I get this Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
 Structure field "buf" was declared as class com.sun.jna.Memory, 
 which is not supported within a Structure
        at com.sun.jna.Structure.writeField(Structure.java:792)
```

Any explanation and/or workaround?
I'm using JNA 4.0

---

The question was answered and accepted, but I want to add this caveat, in case someone is attempting a similar approach:

This is not a good design, because the DLL side will do a realloc of a pointer allocated in the JNA side, and, finally,  the JNA side will attempt to free that pointer (allocated in the DLL side). This is in general not safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `Memory` because it must be possible for JNA to automatically initialize all fields of the structure.

You can certainly give the field `Pointer` type and assign a `Memory` object to it.  The field will generally be preserved as long as the native code does not modify its value.